# How do I prevent a CDN Location redirect for download from Azure from altering the browser location?

Tags: php, azure, file-storage

I'm using the PHP Azure library to create a SAS token for delivering files (File Storage, not blob, and not public) to an authenticated user of a site after they click a link. The link leads to a PHP page where I create the SAS and then issue a Location: header to invoke the downloads. There are no known issues with anything leading up to the final completion of the download.

In the attached image the steps 1-4 are repeated.. one for each file selected.

The issue is that as the URLs are external to the site (CDN) the Location: $url + sas is used. This alters the browser location but is not reflected in the browser... the headers push the file as an attachment.

As mentioned, he user can continue to click other download links on the originating page and they work fine (this is desirable) however the first time they select any link on that same page to go elsewhere on the originating page/site (shown as clicking "home" in the example, the browser true location is revealed (accountname.file.core.windows.net/etc ) and the user gets a Resource not found error originating from the Azure File Storage server. (shown under the chart)

7.10.2017 added this image to illustrate the process used:

[Link to SAS process chart](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4c-1NmKCEfBYUNBNEYxcHBuMEk/view?usp=sharing)

I'm slightly at a loss on how to push a URL download from a CDN without the browser location getting "reset" in this manner. I've done this from local servers/files many times but the Location: $url/SAS aspect is a different dynamic. In my mind, this should behave no differently than pointing the browser to a publicly accessible URL with an EXE that pushes the download, and still allows the user to say on the originating site. I'm starting to think this should be a redirect instead of Location but I haven't found very many Azure/SAS/File Storage examples to back this up. I have to be missing something simple here but it's escaping me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get it correctly, you seem to wanna download the file from Azure storage without changing *address* in the browser by using PHP script.

Basically, you can use `file_get_contents()` function as below to achieve this.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
$response = file_get_contents($SASUri);

echo $response;
```

Comment: Hello Aaron and thank you. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that php will attempt process the file through my server which is not desired. I simply am attempting to "hand off" the delivery to the Azure File Storage CDN via the SASToken. I can accomplish that, however the process is setting up the browser for a navigation failure the moment they click any link that goes somewhere besides the CDN. I updated the OP with a link to an illustration and the error I see.